# Xcode Exc_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, xcode, pointers

so this code is giving me the `Exc_bad_access_code(2)` error and i have no idea why. I think the problem is with the parameters but im not sure, any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y);


/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    char *a = "ASD123";
    swap (a+1 , a+2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string literal.

Change

```
char *a = "ASD123";
```

to

```
char a[] = "ASD123";
```

and your program will work.

In the first case `a` is simply a pointer pointing to a string literal which is in a write protected part of the memory on most platforms, hence the crash because you try to write info write protected memory.

In the second case `a` is a char array of length 7 which is initialized with "ASD123" (6 chars for the string and one char for the terminating zero).

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the complete crash log to be sure, but it's probably that you are attempting to manipulate a string constant:

```
char *a = "ASD123";
swap (a+1 , a+2);
```

which probably lives in read-only memory.

Try:

```
char a[12];
strcpy(a, "ASD123");
swap (a+1 , a+2);
```

or:

```
char a[] = "ASD123";
swap (a+1 , a+2);
```

That will copy the string onto the stack, where it may be modified without issue.  You could also use `strdup()` to copy the string onto the heap (don't forget to call `free()` to release the allocated memory).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `a` correctly. Something like `char a[7] = "ASD123";`

`char* a` only creates a `pointer-to-char`, it does not allocate enough memory to store the characters.